# No sound in Tuxguitar in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sound, tuxguitar

I am not able to get sound from Tuxguitar in Ubuntu 16.04LTS. I have looked at the two existing answers on Ask Ubuntu but the suggestions do not work. I have tried installing and individually selecting each audio output plugin that is available in the repos.

When I select the fluidsynth output plugin, under configuration the audio driver option is greyed out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue with me. Solved by installing tuxguitar-jsa. Type in terminal:

```
sudo apt install tuxguitar-jsa
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides @Shaw post it above, in my case, had to open TuxGuitar > Tools > Settings > Sound > in MidiSequencer select "Real Time Sequencer" and in Midi Port "Gervill"